# Getting file name in hex or base64

Tags: command-line, ls, encoding

Due to [a question on Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/32568/remote-windows-explorer), I thought I could implement a program that parses the output of `ls -l` and displays the files in an Explorer like style. This approach was [suggested on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/242178/213056). At the same time, other people [discourage parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

So I wonder whether there's a way to list the file name in hexadecimal or base64 format which would bypass any special characters like `\n` and similar.

Comment: as in you want to simply convert the ASCII characters in the filename to hexadecimal?

Comment: @TallChuck: I especially want to cover special characters such as `\n` in the file name. Not sure whether `ls` supports Unicode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that you want to display filenames along side their hexadecimal value.  In that case, here is a simple line of code to demonstrate that that is possible:

```
$ touch abc 'd e f' 
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c 'printf "%-10s %s\n" "$1" "$(printf "$1" | xxd -pu )"' None {} \;
./abc      2e2f616263
./d e f    2e2f6420652066
```

The idea is that for each file we find we run `printf` with a format string and two arguments.  The first argument is the file's name and the second is the file's name converted to hex with the utility `xxd`.

Further customization of the output is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Well, call me a noob, but I tried John1024's suggestion and it gave me an error, so I tried figuring it out on my own. I made a file named `readline.sh` that contained the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1      # $1 contains the argument passed
> line.txt   # create/empty line.txt
IFS=$'\n'    # set Internal Field Separator to '\n'
for line in `cat $file`       # assign each line in $file to $line
do
    echo $line >> line.txt    # print $line to line.txt

    # this one's tricky because you need to pipe just the line
    # (without a '\n') into xxd and then print it to line.txt
    echo `printf "%s" "$line" | xxd -p` >> line.txt
done
cat line.txt     # we want to see the contents of line.txt now
```

Now to run it I called `ls | ./readline.sh` and it output the following:

```
bar
626172
baz
62617a
foo
666f6f
line.txt
6c696e652e747874
readline.sh
726561646c696e652e7368
```

Now, I want to point out that this script doesn't have any way of checking that $1 even exists, and there's probably other issues with it, but, assuming I understand your question right, it seems the essence of the solution is to pipe the output of `ls` line by line into `xxd -p`. All the extra fluff was a) for me to make sure it worked before posting it and b) to show the principle in action.

Comment: Thanks. Since I want to get a list of files, I don't want temporary files such as `line.txt` appear in the output. In addition, this requires write access to the directory, which I not always have.